# canvas context coordinates are inconsitent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I am trying to draw on a html5 canvas and the following code should give me a diagonal line from left top to right bottom. However I do not get the expected result. is there any transformation required to the context ?
HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:
     auto;width:700px;height:100px;border:1px solid grey">
</canvas>
```

JS

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
var pen = canvas[0].getContext("2d");    
pen.strokeStyle = "#000000"; pen.lineWidth = "2";    
pen.beginPath(); pen.moveTo(700, 100); pen.lineTo(0,0);
pen.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neilghosh/DvjAP/2/

Comment: I found an workaround at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397315/html5-canvas-distorted but still not sure why CSS doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvjAP/6/)*

Strange but true. The Canvas element W/H have (not only*) to be set *inline* like:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="100"></canvas>
```

Put the rest in your CSS stylesheet:

```
    #myCanvas{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;  
        border:1px solid grey
    }
```

- For a better understanding:
  Canvas element W/H values are: 300x150 by default, but if you change that values in your stylesheet that will actually stretch your canvas renderings like it would do for any other image.
- Another way to change your W/H is with JS like:

  canvas[0].width = 700;
  canvas[0].height = 100;

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvjAP/5/)

Comment: Slight amend: width and height values shouldn’t have `px` suffixes. Dimension values in HTML5 are either pixel values without a suffix or percent values with a `%` suffix.

Comment: @Robin That's true! It might be a fast-typing(non-thinking) error! Thanks for mentioning! Updated.